# No input into the Database

Tags: php, android, google-maps

I want to upload the longitude and latitude from my locationlistener every 5 seconds to my database. I dont know why but i cant connect to it or something else goes wrong. I dont got any errors. I put the latitude and longitude double to a String.

If you can help me guys this would be so great!

RequestQueue requestQueue;
String insertUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/insertlocation.php";

...

And i put this in the oncreate method: `requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());`

...

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location == null)
            return;

        mPositionMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .flat(true)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.motorcycle))
                .anchor(0.5f, 1f)
                .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));

        final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        final double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        String Text = latitude + " " + longitude;
        //Toast.makeText(this, Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("location changed lat", location.getLatitude()+" long: "+location.getLongitude());


        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(Karte.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {


            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Karte.this, "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String lat2string = String.valueOf(latitude);
                String long2string = String.valueOf(longitude);

                parameters.put("longitude", long2string);
                parameters.put("latitude", lat2string);

                return parameters;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

insertlocation.php

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    require 'connection.php';
    createLocation();
}

function createlocation()
{
    global $connect;

    $latitude = $_POST["latitude"];
    $longitude = $_POST["longitude"];

    $query = " Insert into user_info(latitude,longitude) values ('$latitude','$longitude');";

    mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);

}

?>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!
Have you turned on error reporting? What do the webserver's logfiles say?

Also, I've noticed the casing in your function is inconsistent. Although it might work (on some platforms), please use createLocation in both places.

Comment: @YetiCGN, sadly, function names [are case insensitive in all versions of PHP](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php). At least they recommend consistency (as you do).

Comment: You said you can't connect to the database can you show us connection.php code ?

Comment: Resolved it! I tried it on my real device and there is no localhost (genius). So i set up my server and it worked! Thank you guys anyway